# How to setup multiple annotations near the same area

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I've been trying to create an app in swift using MapKit. I've managed to create multiple annotations but every time i try to put a annotation near another one it never shows up. This isn't a big with the code because the second annotation showed up as soon i changed it to a further location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way would be adding the annotations in an array and then looping through the array and adding the annotations on the map. Also you need to adjust the zoom level of the map.

```
let locations = [
    ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
    ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
    ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]

for location in locations {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: I have done that, i still tried putting the locations near each other and only one of them appears.

Comment: `let locations = [
            ["title": "Blue Mountains",    "latitude":-33.499997, "longitude": 150.250000],
            ["title": "Monkey Creek", "latitude": -33.499688, "longitude": 150.260267],
        ]
        
        for location in locations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
            Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }`

Comment: there you go, i don't know if it tagged you to the original comment.

Comment: please add this after the for loop and see if you can see the two pins on the map
`let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
  let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
  let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
  let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.499997, 150.250000)
  let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
  Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)`